# Collaborating with malicious users: In Firebase, is denormalization up to the client?

Tags: firebase

[This blog post describes how to denormalize data in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html).  Ultimately they reveal that this code is necessary in order to add a comment in a properly denormalized way:

```
functon onCommentSubmitted(comment) {
  var root = new Firebase("https://awesome.firebaseio-demo.com");
  var id = root.child("/comments").push();
  id.set(comment, function(err) {
    if (!err) {
      var name = id.key();
      root.child("/links/" + comment.link + "/comments/" + name).set(true);
      root.child("/users/" + comment.author + "/comments/" + name).set(true);
    }
  });
}
```

It bothers me how much you have to trust the client here.  A broken or malicious client could cause some pretty weird stuff by updating the indexes wrong.  For example, they could skip updating the "author" index to post a comment that shows up on the link but not on their own page.  Or they could make the same comment show up in multiple places.

How do you protect the integrity of your indexes?  Is it possible to move this indexing code to Firebase's server side so that it always updates the indexes correctly?

I guess you have to run your own server that listens to all events and updates indexes as needed.  If only Firebase could handle that for you.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to make this more secure is to use Firebase Rules to ensure at each level / depth of your JSON db you have the right permission to read or write.

So in your case, you can make it so `/users` is not writeable by anybody, but `/users/123abc` is only writeable by a user with the uid of 123abc. That way if someone tried to skip the uid and attempt to write `/users/comments/...`, it will respond from Firebase with some sort of a "permissions lacking" message.

More data about security and rules [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).

Server-side updates is certainly a possibility too. However, the beauty of firebase is that the client directly deals with the firebase, which reduces your bandwidth significantly for your server, if you need it. But you can make a case for certain things to only allow your server to write to firebase. For example, you might only want your server to create a user account on firebase.

Hope this helps!

Comment: When you say server, I guess you mean my server, but I was hoping this sort of (what firebase calls denormalization but I just call indexing) could be done entirely in firebase rules.  Can a rule even write unrelated stuff?

Comment: When you login in with a token, whether it's through a provider such as google, or a custom one, you will have a least an auth.uid defined that you can use in your security rules to limit read/write anywhere in your firebase data structure. I have not personally encountered a case where I had to resort to using my server to write to firebase yet. I do use my server for the authentication process and also the firebase token generation. One more thing to add is that you also setup validation rules within the firebase rules section.

Comment: It's not about what keys the user is allowed to write.  It's about whether they maintain the indexes properly.  How can you prevent a bad client from messing up your indexes?  What if they just don't index any of their new content at all?

Comment: Validation is how you can make sure your "indexes" are within a range of acceptable data AND structures.

Comment: Meant to link to the [validation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/regex) section of the docs. Check it and and see if that will suffice for you. Worse case, may want to consider something like sockets.io so you more control over data integrity.

Comment: Unless validations can mutate unrelated data, there's no way they can enforce that denormalization is properly maintained.  Updating denormalization happens in multiple steps anyway.  How can you validate that the user will do something in the future?  You need another agent to do this for you.  I wish Firebase would do it.